# Generate WSDL for classes not used in @WebMethods

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I am developing web services using JAX-WS and using an Object type field in one of my classes. I am using that class as the return value in all of my methods and would like to pass any kind of data for the said field. To be more clear, I want to be able to use this class

```
class Response{

    @XmlElement(name="field1")
    String field1;
    @XmlElement(name="obj")
    Object obj;
}
```

in this method

```
@WebMethod(name="myMethod")
Response myMethod(@WebParam(name="arg")Object arg);
```

and to allow my client to be able to use a class, say

```
class ResponseData{

    @XmlElement(name="somefield")
    String field1;
    @XmlElement(name="someotherfield")
    String field2;
}
```

for the `obj` field in the `Response` class.

What I'm failing to achieve is to put those classes in WSDL without having to create redundant WebMethods taking my classes as objects like

```
@WebMethod(name="redundantMethod")
void redundantMethod(@WebParam(name="data")ResponseData data);
```

I've looked up similar questions on numerous forums (including SO) but couldn't come up with a proper solution. Any help, idea or link is appreciated.